# Please, Java, Printing a calculated result within a chart?

Tags: java, printf

**The overall purpose of program:** determine the surface gravity (g) on each of the 9 planets in our solar system.

(I know, I know... Pluto is not a planet, but it is in this program).

**The problem:**
The program creates the chart and calculates the surface gravity. I need help making the formatting correct- it should be lined up in columns. Also in the process of trying to fix this, I have somehow messed up the program so that it prints the calculated surface area for only one of the planets.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.File;

public class GravityV1
{   

   //print the data
   public static void printResults(String[] names, double[] diameter, double[] mass, int x);
   {
      System.out.printf("%-10s%21.1f%20.4e\n",names[x],diameter[x],mass[x]);          
   }

   //calculate the surface gravity
   public static double calcGravity(double[] m, double[] d)
   {
    double gravity = 0.0;

      for (int i= 0; i < 9; i++) {
        gravity = (((6.67E-11) * (m[i])) / (Math.pow(d[i] / 2, 2)));
      }

    return gravity;        
   }


   //main method
   public static void main (String [ ] args)
   {        
     double[] mass = { 3.30E23, 4.869E24, 5.972E24, 6.4219E23, 1.900E27, 5.68E26, 8.683E25, 1.0247E26, 1.27E22 };

     double[] diameter = { 4880000, 12103000.6, 12756000.3, 6794000, 142984000, 120536000, 51118000, 49532000, 2274000 };

     String[] names = { "Mercury", "Venus", "Earth", "Mars", "Jupiter", "Saturn", "Uranus", "Neptune", "Pluto" };


     System.out.printf("%-7s%20s%20s%25s\n","Planet Name","Diameter","Mass(kg)", "g (m/s^2)");    System.out.println("=============================================================================");

       for (int x = 0; x < 9; x++) {

         printResults(names, diameter, mass, x);

         double surfaceGravity = calcGravity(mass, diameter);

         System.out.println(surfaceGravity);                        
      }  

  System.out.println();
}
```

}

**The output looks like this right now:**

```
Planet Name            Diameter            Mass(kg)                g (m/s^2)
=============================================================================
Mercury               4880000.0          3.3000e+23
0.655252407816091
Venus                12103000.6          4.8690e+24
0.655252407816091
Earth                12756000.3          5.9720e+24
0.655252407816091
Mars                  6794000.0          6.4219e+23
0.655252407816091
Jupiter             142984000.0          1.9000e+27
0.655252407816091
Saturn              120536000.0          5.6800e+26
0.655252407816091
Uranus               51118000.0          8.6830e+25
0.655252407816091
Neptune              49532000.0          1.0247e+26
0.655252407816091
Pluto                 2274000.0          1.2700e+22
0.655252407816091
```

Any help is MUCH appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
System.out.printf("%-10s%21.1f%20.4e",names[x],diameter[x],mass[x]); // removed 2 characters

System.out.printf("%.21f\n", surfaceGravity); // play with number to get it right
```

Comment: thank you both so much, your combined answers worked, except how do I put space in between? The first line looks like this (but all on one line): Mercury 4880000.0 3.3000e+233.697090835796829000000

Comment: I guess I did not play with them enough, "%26.10f\n" was perfect. thank you again

Answer (score 1):

Your `calcGravity` method computes the surface gravity for all planets, and returns the last one. Instead of doing that, it probably should compute the surface gravity for one particular planet only:

```
public static double calcGravity(double m, double d)
{
 double gravity = (((6.67E-11) * (m)) / (Math.pow(d / 2, 2)));
 return gravity;        
}
```

Then you would call this method with the data of a particular planet, not with the data of all planets:

```
double surfaceGravity = calcGravity(mass[x], diameter[x]);
```

Comment: see above comment please :) Thank you!

Comment: Which comment do you refer to?

Comment: Sorry Joni, I meant to ask you the same question about the formatting I commented on the above answer, but arkonautom answered it. Thanks again for your time.